# Warning: Failed propType: Invalid props.style key 'color' supplied to [ 'View' | 'RCTView' ]

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I Used the color property in React native, When show this Warning.
I Using React-Native Version: 0.57.

**Code:**

```
display: {
    flex: 2,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: "white"
  },
```

**Error**

[image: Warning: Failed propType: Invalid props.style key 'color' supplied to [ 'View' | 'RCTView' ]]

Comment: Edit your question and provide the impacted code as well.

Comment: color is not a valid style props in react-native. view their docs on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props

Comment: Are you aplying this style on a View ?

Comment: @Balanced02 It's a Web component okay, When How to change Text Color

Comment: @DanielGabor yes I applying the style on a View.

Comment: @NgSharma I meant on a View tag. Did't specify it initially

Comment: @Balanced02 Okay I Under Stand, i remove it.

Comment: @Balanced02 Okay View tag Does not supported color property. I apply this Color tag on Text tag,  it's work.

Comment: @NgSharma Cool...

Answer (score 1):

You already set `backgroundColor` which is supported property by `View` component so simply removing this:

`color: "white"`

will get rid of the warning. Like someone already mentioned `color` is not valid style property for `View`, see:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props